# Could there be any possible issues with this ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, mvvm

Are there any possible errors with the ViewModel below?
In other words, is there any part of the code that is likely to create any issues?
Please advise. 
Thank you.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_text, value))
                return;
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue with this VM or after someone to review your code ?

Comment: looks good a little shorter way could be                                                          
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

Answer (score 1):

You may have some threading issues if the `OnPropertyChanged` method is invoked from different threads. You may possibly end up having `NullReferenceException` thrown if there is any `PropertyChanged` event unscubscriptions happening on the other thread paralellely. When you intially check `PropertyChanged` for not null, it may come out as true, but the next line when you try to invoke the handler, it may be null. So the right and recommend way of doing it is shown below. Also You can enhance the method by adding the `[CallerMemberNameAttribute]` to the `propertyName` argument to avoid typos while passing the value for propertyName. With the attribute specified to the argument, you don't have to pass the property name for the property being changed. You just need to call the method with no arguments and the attribute will take care of passing the appropriate property name value.

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName=null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```